# Deep Learning, recommandation regarding which architecture to use

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I'm currently developping an application which allows psychologists to manage their schedule and budget. As a proof of concept, I would like to create an intelligent appointment service. There can be 3 cases:

```
I know the client, I need to guess the day and time for his next appointment
I know the day, I need to guess which client and at what time
I know nothing, I need to guess which client, which day and what time
```

I'm currently in the process of learning deep learning algorithms just to get a bit of theory, but it's a little bit overwhelming.

There are features I know I can extract from the appointments:

```
Day preference in the week (always on monday, say)
Reccurence (every two weeks or such)
Nb of days since last appointment
Whether the client was present or not to his last appointment
etc..
```

I know there are things like "features extraction" that you can train a neural network to find the features itself, but all examples refers to image recognition or speech analysis.

I want the algorithm to train on the existing and future appointments (stored in a MongoDB). I would also like that the algorithm trains live, that is if it proposes an appointment to the user and the user takes it, it should train positively. On the other hand, if the user navigates or change any parameter, the algorithm should adjust its weights accordingly.

I also know I should start by extracting data from the DB that will be transformed in a vector or matrix, then the algorithm is supposed to train on that data.

Is this correct? How can I start and what kind of architecture do I need?

Answer (score 1):

Since It's a POC, I assume you don't have a large dataset, I would not recommend to go with deep learning, start with something smaller like a decision tree kind of algo and when you have good amount of data, move to deep models. Why? It's always easier to tweak the tree kind of model and explain it to client too. Also, as suggested by Prof Andrew NG, Deep learning require at least 100K observations to learn and perform well. With simulated dataset, it's always unpredictable.

Comment: Hey Outlier! Thanks for your answer! Suppose I have I year of data ~1000 records. Couldn't I train a deep network by presenting it the same dataset over and over again? Say a record for training that contains information regarding the past appointments and such, I could generate real data like so:

`record: date, time, client, nbDaysSinceLastAppointment, nLastWeekAppointments`

knowing that nLastAppointments would be x past week of data. That way, I could recursively match a single appointment with one or many history weeks?

Comment: No, by repeating, you can not create bigger data, though you can use higher learning rate your dataset and use multiple epoch. You should keep a check that you are not overtraining/overfitting. If you do, you can use ResNets in that case.